# How to have both componentWillUnmount and componentDidUpdate hook equivalents in the same React Stateless Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Many articles state how to replace react's lifecycle methods with react hooks.(here an example:[[https://sebhastian.com/react-hooks-useeffect/]](https://sebhastian.com/react-hooks-useeffect/)).

For the **componentDidUpdate** or **componentDidMount**, usually it's using **useEffect** hook with parameters passed as an array to watch and trigger when their value change :

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Hello I'm ${name} and I'm a ${role}`);
  }, [name, role] );
```

While for the **componentWillUnmount**, it's also the **useEffect** hook but with an empty array

```
useEffect(() => {
    this._initGraph();

    return () => { this.graph = this.graph.destroy(); }
  }, [] );
```

Now my question is how to have both **componentWillUnmount** and **componentDidUpdate** hook equivalents in the same React Stateless Functional Component ?
Is it okay to use useEffect hook several times in the same Stateless Component ?!

Comment: _" Is it okay to use useEffect hook several times in the same Stateless Component ?!"_ - yes, hooks can be called/used multiple times.

Comment: if you use Hooks the functional component is not Stateless, you got useState Hook to work with state